# Java GUI Buttons will not print string to interface

Tags: java, string, user-interface, button

GUI Beginner here.

My problem is not creating a GUI interface, but having the 2 buttons print the string in the JTextArea inside the interface.
The first "learned" button takes a random element from the array and prints it.
The second button "clear" is just supposed to print a string when pressed
I have action listeners for both buttons, but still cant quite get it.

Thanks for your time.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;


public class GUI extends JFrame {


String [] sentences = {"Random sentence 1", "random sentence 2", "random sentence 3", "random sentence 4", random sentence 5", "random sentence 6"};


private Container contents;
JButton learned = new JButton("Learned");
JButton clear = new JButton("Clear");
JTextArea clearDisplay;


public GUI()
{
    super ("GUI"); //title bar text

    contents = getContentPane ();
    contents.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); //make buttons appear

    //set the layout manager

    //instantiate buttons
    learned = new JButton("I Learned");
    clear = new JButton("Clear");

    //add components to window
    contents.add(learned);
    contents.add(clear);



    //instantiate event handler
    ButtonHandler bh = new ButtonHandler ();

    //add event handler as listener for both buttons
    learned.addActionListener (bh);
    clear.addActionListener(bh);

    setSize (400, 200); //size of window
    setVisible (true); //see the window

    }


   public class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener
   {
    //implement ActionPerformed method

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        Container contentPane = getContentPane();
       if (e.getSource() == learned)
       {
         String random = (sentances[new Random().nextInt(sentances.length)]); //random from array           
         JTextArea learned = new JTextArea(random);
       }
       else if (e.getSource() == clear)           
       {
            JTextArea clearDisplay = new JTextArea("This is where it will display what I learned. \\nMessage Displayed Here.");
       }

    }

}

public static void main(String[] args)
{  
   GUI basicGui = new GUI (); 
   basicGui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //program exits on close                              
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

```
else if (e.getSource() == clear)           
   {
        JTextArea clearDisplay = new JTextArea("This is where it will display what I learned. \\nMessage Displayed Here.");
   }
```

You are creating a new JTextArea that never gets added to the GUI. you should write it like that:

```
else if (e.getSource() == clear)           
   {
        clearDisplay = new JTextArea("This is where it will display what I learned. \\nMessage Displayed Here.");
   }
```

And add it to the GUI.

You should also think about a different approach: First create the JTextField, add it to the GUI and then only change its text in the code above.

Also, you have some typos here:

```
String random = (sentances[new Random().nextInt(sentances.length)]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't create new JTextAreas within your action listener. Rather create one single JTextArea in the GUI's constructor and in the listeners, simply write the appropriate text to the JTextArea, either by calling `.setText(...)` if you want to completely change the text, or `.append(...)` if you want to add additional text to existing text.

Comment: added public JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(); to the constructor.
and in the components section added  contents.add(textArea);
Then action events added textArea.setText(random); and textArea.setText("This....");   and it WROKED!    Many thanks!